# Поиск и вывод из файла двузначных чисел на консоль

Tags: java, файлы

Пытаюсь реализовать вывод из файла в консоль строк, в которых есть двузначные числа. Вывод из файла всех строк реализовал, но не могу поделить строки на слова и вывести то, что надо:

```
while ((line = fin.readLine()) != null) 
    String[] newline = line.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < newline.length; i++) { 
        if (newline[i].length() == 2)
            System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: `в которых есть двузначные числа` -- все-таки числ**а** или одно число? Приведите возможные варианты подходящих строк.

Comment: @ post_zeew  хотя бы одно число
к примеру: ewrtertertyrty 22 wrteer ertey dfgdf
Нужно проверить является ли элемент поделенной строки двузначным числом

Comment: Эта строка: `abc55ab fghj sfh` удовлетворяет Вашему условию? Двузначное число всегда отделено пробелом от всего остального?

Comment: @ post_zeew подойдет

Comment: @ post_zeew да, можно просто посимвольно проверять нет ли двух чисел рядом, но я не знаю как :С

Comment: @DaveManston а вы этот код откуда брали и почему даже не пытались его запустить?

Comment: @ Regent сам писал, но он не работает

Comment: @DaveManston конечно, не работает. Он даже не компилируется: я в представленном коде исправил 3 ошибки, дабы он хотя бы компилировался успешно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант посимвольного анализа строки (для поиска чисел в строках наподобие `abc55ab fghj sfh`) с помощью детерминированного конечного автомата:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            int state = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length() + 1; i++)
            {
                boolean isDigit = (i < line.length() && isDigit(line.charAt(i)));
                if ((state == 0 || state == 1) && isDigit)
                {
                    state++;
                }
                else if (state == 2 && !isDigit)
                {
                    System.out.println(line.substring(i - 2, i));
                    state = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    state = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ingored) { }
}

private static boolean isDigit(char c)
{
    return (c >= 48 && c <= 57);
}
```

В консоль выводятся сами двузначные числа. Если нужно выводить строки (по одному разу), содержащие эти числа, то код

```
System.out.println(line.substring(i - 2, i));
state = 0;
```

нужно заменить на

```
System.out.println(line);
break;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь огромное